# VS Code terminal highlights prompt

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After accepting the recent Windows 10 update, my VS Code editor terminal has changed colours and contrast. Any attempt at changing the Theme still has the command prompt highlight in these inverted/obnoxious colours (dirs, files are hard to see).

It happened just after updating my Windows 10 OS; That spec - Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 1809, Installed on 29/05/2019, OS Build 17763.529

My VS Code application spec - Version 1.34.0 (user setup), commit a622c65...ending in 5fe758

[image]

Comment: I think that'd be better suited in a bug report over at [VS Code's GitHub Ticket Tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues)...

Comment: Could very be how your PS1 is set up are leaving any remaining coloring things or not resetting right?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner yes thanks, i have done that - here it is FYI;
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74567

Comment: @HSchmale I have never really used PS1 on this machine, but will look into those settings now, thank you.